# Taking a picture with a laptop webcam after entering an incorrect password

Tags: linux, security, password, camera, screen-lock

I'd like to set up my laptop so that if a wrong password is entered when the screen is locked, a picture is taken using the laptop's webcam. I examined `xlock` (from *xlockmore* package), but there is no option to run a customized action when a wrong password is entered.

There is a similar question on SuperUser, but only targets Windows: [Taking a picture after entering wrong password](https://superuser.com/q/553301/162491).

(For those who like funny cat photos: [My laptop is set up to take a picture after 3 incorrect password attempts](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yohbt.jpg).)

Comment: Have you checked this https://github.com/jeroennijhof/pam_script

Comment: you might have an answer here as well http://askubuntu.com/questions/253189/can-i-make-the-webcam-take-a-picture-when-an-incorrect-password-is-entered

Comment: @mazs Thanks, that's more or less what I was looking for.

Comment: Now I understand why all those hacker guys are working in hoodies in a dark room.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Copied [this post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/253189/can-i-make-the-webcam-take-a-picture-when-an-incorrect-password-is-entered) on ask Ubuntu by [gertvdijk](https://askubuntu.com/users/88802/gertvdijk), pointed out by [mazs](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/137578/mazs) in the comments. In the effort of closing this question.

---

Based on [this post](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1509424&p=9827947#post9827947) on the Ubuntuforums by [BkkBonanza](https://ubuntuforums.org/member.php?u=550406).

This is an approach using PAM and will work for all failed login attempts. Using SSH, a virtual terminal or via the regular login screen, it doesn't matter as everything is handled by PAM in the end.

1. Install [ffmpeg](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/ffmpeg/), we're going to use this as a command line way of grabbing the webcam images. Update: ffmpeg is removed when you upgrade to Ubuntu 14.04. We can use avconv in place of ffmpeg in the below script. No need to install anything separately.
2. Create a small script somewhere, e.g. `/usr/local/bin/grabpicture` with the following content

   ```
   #!/bin/bash
   ts=`date +%s`
   ffmpeg -f video4linux2 -s vga -i /dev/video0 -vframes 3 /tmp/vid-$ts.%01d.jpg
   exit 0  #important - has to exit with status 0
   ```

   Change the /dev/video0 with the actual video device of your webcam and choose a path where the pictures are being saved - I just choose `/tmp`. In the newer version of Ubuntu use `avconv` instead of `ffmpeg` (`sudo apt-get install libav-tools`).
3. Make it executable, e.g. `chmod +x /usr/local/bin/grabpicture`.
4. Test it, by just calling it: `/usr/local/bin/grabpicture`. Check if you see files appearing in `/tmp/vid....jpg`.
5. Configure PAM to call this on every failed attempt.

   Note: do this carefully - if this fails you'll not be able to gain access to your system again in a regular way.

   1. Open a terminal window with root access (sudo -i) and leave it open - just in case you screw up in the next steps.
   2. Open `/etc/pam.d/common-auth` in your favourite editor, e.g. by doing `gksudo gedit /etc/pam.d/common-auth`. Keep in mind for the following steps that order of lines in this file matters.
   3. Locate the line below. By default there's one line before the one with `pam_deny.so`. On my 12.04 system it looks like this:

      ```
      auth    [success=1 default=ignore]      pam_unix.so nullok_secure
      ```
   4. In this line change the success=1 to success=2 to have it skip our script on succes. This is an important step.
   5. Right below there, add a new one to call the actual script:

      ```
      auth    [default=ignore]                pam_exec.so seteuid /usr/local/bin/grabpicture
      ```
   6. Save and close the file. No need to restart anything.
6. Test it.

   1. In a new terminal window, as regular user, try `su -l username` to log in as another user with username `username` (change with an actual one of course). Deliberately enter the wrong password. Check if this result in a new picture.
   2. The same as above, but now enter the correct password. Check if you log in and it doesn't result in a picture being taken.
7. If the tests have succeeded you can log out from your DE (Unity/KDE/...) and you should see the same when entering a wrong password from the login screen.